# How many thread should I use to send and receive data with java.nio?

Tags: java, scala, java.nio.file

I am creating a distributed system with many machines for learning. I need to send and receive data between machines, and I am using java.nio to create that network. In one machine, I use one thread for serversocketchannel to receive data from other machines, and use for each package of data I create new thread to send it. It means that one thread for receiving and multiple threads for sending in one machines.

But I face a problem that since one thread handles receiving, many client will be pending when connecting. 
Should I change it to one thread handles receiving and one thread handles sending?
Thank you
P/s: I don't want to use any 3rd party framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more senders than receivers in your network, then obviously some of the senders will end up waiting. If you have more receivers than senders, then obviously some of the receivers will be idle, since nearly all of the time a sender will probably be connected to a receiver, one to one.

---

I cannot judge on what you "should do" as I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Anyway, the two common patterns used on the receiver side are:

- One thread handles all
- One thread handles just accepting the connection and opening the stream, then delegates the actual work with the stream to another thread (usually from a thread pool to prevent resource exhaustion that could happen if a new thread was created for every connection)

Comment: This is my case. I have 4 machines. At some points, machine #1 need to receive 10000 bytes from the other three. You mean that in machine #1 I can use 2 threads, the 1st thread can accept connection and open the stream, then transfer to another thread to receive bytes, then that 1st thread return to listen to new coming connections again?. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's the common approach. Usually, you don't know how many senders there will be though (e.g. with a web server). You'll still need as many "worker" threads on server as there are sender threads in the network (plus one thread that just accepts connections and delegates work to workers) for all senders to be serviced at the same time.

Comment: but, I am using java nio, how can you separate two parts in java nio? this is how I implement my server thread
https://gist.github.com/hminle/0e4a18ad5b3b37ee57348e673c5262fd